# service has paused on pressing power button in android

Tags: android

I am using an IntentService which runs in background. When i press power button my service has paused...and resumed when screen is on...

But i want to run my service even after pressing power button.

How can i achieve my requirement?

i tried with PowerManager in onStart() but not working.

```
PowerManager mgr = (PowerManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
            WakeLock wakeLock = mgr.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "MyWakeLock");
            wakeLock.acquire();
```

Comment: on which devices you have tried?

Comment: micormax A89...Is this issue related with devices?

Comment: Maybe. In my sony xperia device. if stamina mode is on this happened too. so please try this on other device and run some more tests.

Comment: ok..but i can't force my app users to use particular device right..So is there any way to override power button functionality...

Comment: yes you can not but the ultimate control of the power management is in user's hand. If I turn on stamina mode when I am running low on battery. Locking the screen pauses all non system services to save the battery. I dont blame the application or the developer. Its the system policy. because System service > app service.

Answer (score -1):

Cross check for wake lock permission in your Manifest.

uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"

Comment: It may be device specific issue then( not sure), similar thread https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/taS0FzaTmio